# Looking for a more granular way to organize Rails models and understanding autoloader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, model, autoload, zeitwerk

In a test application (Rails 7.0, Ruby 3.2) I'm currently experimenting with a different structure of models than the default. The idea was to have something like this where all related code of a model lives together and each group uses same naming for support files:

```
app/
└── models/
    ├── accounts
    │   ├── account.rb
    │   └── support
    │       └── greetable.rb
    └── users
        ├── user.rb
        └── support
            └── greetable.rb
```

This was how I imagined the files of this setup:

```
# models/accounts/account.rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  include Greetable
end

# models/accounts/support/greetable.rb
module Greetable
  def greet
    "Hello, Account!"
  end
end

# models/users/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Greetable
end

# models/users/support/greetable.rb
module Greetable
  def greet
    "Hello, User!"
  end
end
```

Any idea how to define autoload config for this setup? Was hoping Zeitwerk does its magic and automatically finds the closest Greetable module but this is not how it works.

All thoughts/ideas/discussions around this topic are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure anything. You just have to understand how its intented to work.

The way that Zeitwerk works is that it expects any files in subdirectories of an autoloading root (any subfolder or app and `/app/models/concerns`, `/app/controllers/concerns`) to be nested in a module (or class) with the a name according to the folder:

```
# models/users/support/greetable.rb
module Users
  module Support
    module Greetable
      def greet
        "Hello, User!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Zeitwerk will automatically create the implicit namespaces (the modules) so even if your file just contains:

```
module Greetable
  def greet
    "Hello, User!"
  end
end
```

Zeitwerk will nest the constant as `Users::Support::Greetable`. I'm guessing this "didn't work" because you where expecting `Greetable` to be in the top level namespace.

This is not just what Zeitwerk expects but also what other developers expect and is the accepted method of organizing your code as the encapsulation provided by module nesting prevents conflicts. This isn't actually something unique to Zeitwerk either - it really just codifies conventions that were used long before its invention.

Plopping everything into the global namespace in Rails is something we do out of convenience while ignorning the warning bells that are going off in the back of our heads. Its far from an ideal way to organize code.

While you could make this nested file constant a top level constant by using collapsing or adding additional autoloading roots from an organizational standpoint I would really question why you would want violate the principle of least suprise like this as it provides no real benefits.

Comment: thanks for sharing your honest opinion, I'm here to learn and discuss different approaches. Not sure if I fully got your suggestion but I tried putting it in a PR here: https://github.com/Florian-Suchan-Holding-GmbH/demo-app/pull/2

There were initial errors because it didn't find Account or User class and I had to call Accounts::Account.new.greet first, resulting in an error before Account.new.greet succeeded. Same for user. Any thoughts on getting around those?

Also if you'd like to share a completely different approach, please go ahead, repo is public.

Comment: My thoughts are really just that you should spend some time learning the basics about how [module lookup works in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html) and how [the autoloader works](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-engines). I don't know exactly what issues you encountered but I'm pretty sure they are pretty easy to solve if you just understand the fundamentals. There are also many blogs about how to organize large Rails projects - you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: For example given `app/models/accounts/account.rb` you can just do `include Support::Greetable`. And it will resolve the constant to `Accounts::Support::Greetable` as that's the current module nesting.

Comment: Wouldn't bother anyone if it was that obvious: The only working example rn is [here](https://github.com/Florian-Suchan-Holding-GmbH/demo-app/pull/2/files).

Which means I have to call `Accounts::Account.new` for a new instance of that class. `Account.new` is what I'm looking for, shortening the include nice to have.

Comment: Why put the file in the `accounts` folder then?

Comment: Anticipating 100s of classes in `app/models` in the future, the idea was to group everything that's related. Having `account.rb` in `app/models` does work, I'm aware of that.

Comment: Yeah, but if you have 100s of classes do you think putting them all into the global namespace is a good idea? Coming from a PHP background I have seen that and its horrifying. Organizing code its not just about spreading it out into subfolders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252487/discussion-between-floriansuchan-and-max).

Answer (score 1):

The basic premise in Zeitwerk is that a root directory (called "autoload path" in Rails) represents a concrete, fixed namespace. By default, that namespace is the top-level one, `Object`.

The expected naming in that subtree is then relative to that root. So, with default settings, `app/models` is `Object`, and `app/models/accounts` is `Accounts`.

There is a feature of Zeitwerk thought for grouping files together for organizational purposes, without introducing namespaces. That is [collapsing](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#collapsing-directories).

What you want to accomplish is possible via collapsing (untested):

```rb
# config/initializers/autoloading.rb

main = Rails.autoloaders.main
main.collapse("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*")
main.collapse("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*/support")
```

As the documentation says, those glob patterns are evaluated on boot and again on each reload, so if you add new groups under `app/models` they will be picked up.

Comment: While you could do this I would absolutely hate you for it as a maintainer. If you want to plop everything into the global namespace at least don't make me go hunting through three levels of folders to find the corresponding file.

Comment: I am here to help, not to judge. People may experiment with ideas as they please.

Comment: @XavierNoria thanks for reaching out, tried out your suggestion and threw it in a PR https://github.com/Florian-Suchan-Holding-GmbH/demo-app/pull/1

Unfortunately calling `Account.new.greet` and `User.new.greet` both returned "Hello Account!", so it seems it has an issue with the exact same name of Greetable module without any namespace, what do you think?

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I missed you wanted the same module to be defined in multiple files. That is not possible, see https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#shadowed-files.

Comment: You have also to think that, even if you work without an autoloader, in pure Ruby you cannot have two different `Greetable` modules. That constant is global, it can store one object only.